# DB2 LUW double-byte characters not decoded on prod db , but in test db they are decoded

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud, database-administration, db2-luw

I have an application that saves url meta data and the double byte characters correctly save in our test db when running the application locally, but our prod dB doesn’t…

Not sure what’s going on, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Column data type is varchar.[image]

Comment: Are both test and prod set up the same way including the same code page and accessed using the same client and code page?

Comment: Everything is the same, except In test, the application runs local host but saves the scraped data to our replica prod dB both hosted in the cloud. Basically the only difference is where the application runs… local host for test and in the cloud for prod.

Comment: Then investigate the difference and how that impacts the data. It seems to impact character conversion

Comment: Add the same data to the two databases. Then edit your question to show both the strings, __and__ the HEX(CONTENT_DSCR) output from both databases. Also edit your question to add which tool you are using to insert the data,  and which tool you use to view the data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by setting the locale in our Docker file to utf-8.

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y locales locales-all
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
```